# Как в C# можно разбить массив на несколько массивов с сохранением всех данных?

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый вечер.

Мне необходимо разбить массив на несколько с сохранением всех данных. К примеру в массиве `ArrayList` содержится 1103 значения, как можно его разбить на 10 массивов с сохранением всех значений?

В PHP для этого используется функция [array_chunk](http://php.ru/manual/function.array-chunk.html).

Как с этим обстоят дела в шарпе?

Спасибо.

Comment: Почему же `ArrayList`, 21-й век на дворе, используйте `List<T>` же.

Comment: В List<T> это возможно? Можно пример?

Comment: @Jofsey, странный сайт лимитирует комментарии. 
Для того, чтобы сделать полностью ленивый алгоритм, работающий за один проход, придется руками реализовать ДКА аналогичный тому, что компилятор генерирует для вызовов yield. Не самое интересное занятие, но можете попробовать сделать и выложить результат сюда.

@VladD, если при изменение понадобится абстракция, я ее введу. Про инваринаты вам сначала надо указать на что вы их накладываете и в чем они состоят. Для этого вам придется многое в этой задаче додумать. Я гаданием предпочитаю не заниматься. Достаточно, что конкретно ToChunks корректен.

Comment: @STDray: (1) неужели инвариант не очевиден? последовательность элементов кусков совпадает с исходной последовательностью хотя бы в случае, если она неизменна. (2) в production-коде у вас не выйдет так просто менять сигнатуры методов, если, конечно, над проектом работает больше 1 человека. кроме того, не отлавливаемое компилятором изменение мутабельных списков — источник wtf ("мне передали `List<T>` в подпрограмму, какого я не должен менять его?") и багов. (не думать — не всегда наилучшая стратегия, потом может быть слишком поздно.)

Comment: Если кто решит менять куски, значит такого инварианта на соответствие исходной коллекции нет. При том неважно, будет ли мутирован список или порождена новая коллекция.
Конечно у меня выйдет менять сигнатуры, иначе зачем нам типизированные языки.
Если человеку передали список, он волен его менять. Все правильно.

Comment: @STDray: Ага, и каждое изменение сигнатуры вашего метода обязано вызывать каскадные изменения всего кода, который его использует? Сегодня вы используете `List`, и ваши клиенты пользуются методами `Add`/`Remove`, завтра вы перешли на `ConcurrentReadOnlyList`, клиенты переписали снова весь код и пользуются контейнером из разных потоков, завтра вы убрали `Concurrent` и им снова переписывать всё? Я вам скажу неожиданную штуку: интерфейсы должны быть стабильны. Сигнатура не значит лишь "моя функция делает это сегодня", она значит "моя функция будет делать это". Breaking changes — всегда плохо.

Comment: @STDray: кроме того, для функции с именем `ToChunks` _я_ бы ожидал выполнения описанного инварианта. Дать возможность клиентам свободно разрушать инвариант — примерно то же, что оставлять приватные данные класса в публичной видимости, и требовать от клиентов, чтобы они "знали что делают". На мой взгляд, безответственная позиция.

Comment: @VladD, для функции ToChunks инваринат выполняется. Нарушить его можно только определенным использованием результата в контексте какой-то другой задачи. Клиенты ведут себя аналогичным образом - выдвигают требования на используемые структуры данных, которые должны быть минимальными. Если им придется что-то переписывать, значит они сформировали требования некорректно. Это общий принцип - фокусироваться на своей конкретной задаче, а не домысливать за других в условиях недостаточной информации.

Comment: @STDray: И без требований клиентов вы должны предоставлять структуру данных, ведущую себя ожидаемым, надёжным образом. Дизайн правильной структуры данных не стоит взваливать на клиента, примерьте на себя роль архитектора.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, по всякому можно.

Например, так:

```
var nChunks = 10;
var totalLength = source.Count();
var chunkLength = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalLength / (double)nChunks);
var parts = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                      .Select(i => source.Skip(i * chunkLength).Take(chunkLength));
```

Если нужны везде "материализованные" массивы, добавьте `.ToList()`:

```
var parts = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                      .Select(i => source.Skip(i * chunkLength)
                                         .Take(chunkLength)
                                         .ToList())
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @z668: пожалуйста!

Comment: @STDray: (сорри, лимит комментариев) Это всё понятно, я собственно о другом. Сам по себе паттерн "обрабатываем куски коллекций последовательно" нужен достаточно редко, если вообще нужен (мне не был нужен ни разу), агрегировать можно точно так же по одному элементу. (Зачем разделение на куски ТС, он не уточнял.) Поэтому дополнительное усиление семантики кажется мне немотивированным.

---
Говоря о структурах данных, если уж возвращать материализованные данные, то `IEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<T>>` по понятным причинам.

Comment: @VladD, если у вас есть какие-то критерии нужности, лучше их указать сразу. И понятные причины тоже надо указать, поскольку я уже написал, что важно знать с какой именно коллекцией имеем дело. Если кратко, я руководствуюсь принципом: минимальные требования на входе, максимальные - на выходе.

Comment: @STDray: понятная причина — это то, что `List<T>` является изменяемым. После изменения списка, очевидно, он больше не является валидным куском исходной коллекции.

Comment: @VladD, это уже заботы пользователя функции.

Comment: @STDray: нуууу... Вы же вчера были за то, чтобы тип указывал на список валидных операций, нет? Если пользователю нужно думать "это `List<T>`, но я не должен в него писать", почему бы в таком случае не заставить его думать "это `IEnumerable<T>`, но на самом деле там внутри `List<T>`"? Одинаково неправильно, не находите?

Comment: Что такое "валидные операции"? Я говорил о том, зная поставленную задачу можно выдвинуть требования к структурам данных. Я так же написал, что на входе требования должны быть минимальными, но достаточными для данной задачи. Для выходных данных, я должен оценить все допустимые сценарии их использования (заведомый фейл) и выбрать подходящую структуру, либо же вернуть максимально полную информацию о результате, предоставив пользователю возможность самому решать, как и что делать с результатом ToChunks. Если он захочет потерять часть информации о типе, то сделает это сам.

Comment: @STDray: Вы, наверное, не до конца поняли. Если вы возвращаете пользователю `List<T>`, вы тем самым обещаете, что валидной операцией (не нарушающей семантики данных) является в частности изменение данных, а также их удаление. А это очевидным образом не так.

---
Возвращать "максимально конкретный" тип результата, на мой взгляд, не лучший путь: этим вы не оставляете пути для дальнейших улучшений. Даже если вы хотите дать пользователю доп. гарантии (что может оказаться неверно в перспективе), надо декларировать минимальный интерфейс/тип, дающий эти гарантии.

Comment: @STDray

- Извините, что вклиниваюсь, но использование `IEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<T>>` здесь — это отличный пример [`defensive copying`](http://goo.gl/Ts6pN) по `Joshua Bloch.` Зачем методу возвращать `mutable` коллекцию и заставлять пользователя думать над причинами этой самой `mutab'ельности`? Если пользователю в какой-то момент нужно как-то изменить `immutable` результат метода, пускай он явно в своем коде проектирует результат в `IList<T>` и работает с его копией.

- И почему, раз уж на то пошло, `IEnumerable<List<T>>`, а не `IEnumerable<IList<T>>`?

Comment: @@VladD @Котик_хочет_кушать, исходная коллекция не изменяется. После вызова ToChunks все инварианты выполняются. Абстракции и ограничения зависят от юз-кейсов. Если у вас есть предположения относительно дальнейшего использования, тогда имеет место контракт по данным и для его выполнения выбирается минимальная соответствующая структура данных (или абстракция над ней). Я же никаких подобных предположений не делал, потому вернул всю имеющуюся имеющуюся информацию, то есть фактический тип результата. Кроме того C# императивный язык и не факт, что обосновывать надо мутабельность, а не наоборот.

Comment: @STDray: (1) вы и правда не видите, почему не стоит возвращать конкретный тип результата? вам никогда не приходилось изменять имплементацию? (2) Возможность мутации кусков означает неконтролируемое нарушение инварианта. Императивность тут не при чём, нельзя позволять операции, ведущие к неконсистентности данных, в любой системе. Тем более, язык легко позволяет выразить иммутабельность.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу.

Ленивые вычисления, конечно, хорошо, но не стоит забывать про эффективность и повторное использование. Имеет смысл реализовать функцию, которая разобьет коллекцию на куски заданного размера за один проход.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> ToChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int chunkSize) {
    List<T> chunk = new List<T>(chunkSize);
    foreach (var item in items) {
        chunk.Add(item);
        if (chunk.Count == chunkSize) {
            yield return chunk;
            chunk = new List<T>(chunkSize);
        }
    }
    if (chunk.Any())
        yield return chunk;
}
```

Если требуется именно разбить коллекцию на N кусков, то стоит удостовериться, что сложность получения количества элементов в исходной коллекции будет O(1). Потом вычислить размер куска и вызвать функцию, описанную выше.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> ToNChunks<T>(this IReadOnlyCollection<T> items, int chunksCount) {
    var chunkSize = items.Count / chunksCount;
    return items.ToChunks(chunkSize);
}
```

Описать как методы расширения и использовать для соответствующих коллекций. ([Пример](http://pastebin.com/1uGgHbMk))

ЗЫ: От использования ArrayList и других нетипизированных коллекций лучше отказаться.

ЗЗЫ: По мотивам возникшего флуда. Реализация, позволяющего выбрать тип чанков

```
static IEnumerable<R> ToChunks<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> items, 
    int chunkSize, Func<List<T>, R> toChunk) 
    where R : IEnumerable<T> {
    var chunk = new List<T>(chunkSize);
    foreach (var item in items) {
        chunk.Add(item);
        if (chunk.Count == chunkSize) {
            yield return toChunk(chunk);
            chunk = new List<T>(chunkSize);
        }
    }
    if (chunk.Any())
        yield return toChunk(chunk);
}
```

Например так

```
public static IEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> ToChunks<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, int chunkSize) {
    return items.ToChunks(chunkSize, x => x);
}
```

В любом случае, есть выражение "преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех бед", тоже самое касается и абстракций в ООП.

ЗЗЗЫ: Полностью ленивое решение

```
static IEnumerable<T> TakeN<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        yield return enumerator.Current;
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            break;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ToChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int chunkSize) {
    using (var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator()) 
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
            yield return TakeN(enumerator, chunkSize);
}
```

Comment: +1, хотя не совсем понятен смысл полуленивой коллекции (`IEnumerable<List<T>>` вместо полностью ленивого `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` или полностью материализованного `List<List<T>>`).

Comment: @VladD, сформировать ленивый IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> за один проход сложно, ведь вызовы Skip(K * N).Take(N) приводят к неоднократному повторному итерированию по исходной коллекции. А энергичный List<List<T>> может слишком дорого обойтись по памяти, требуя при этом, тот же самый один проход. Мой типичный сценарий - получать данные из внешнего источника и кусками их обрабатывать. Полагаться на то, что у меня хватит памяти на всё, я не могу.

Comment: @STDray: тем не менее, вы полагаетесь на то, что на _один_ кусок памяти хватит. Не уверен, что полностью ленивое разбиение вообще возможно, по крайней мере, я не вижу очевидного пути. (Это осложняется тем, что пользователь может _сначала_ пробежать по _последнему_ куску.)

Comment: @VladD, на один кусок хватит, ведь я сам выбираю его размер. Я хотел сделать акцент на выбираемых структурах данных. Если правильно их подбирать, понимая их устройство, то можно избежать всяких осложнений. Например, зная, что в общем случае даже Count() для IEnumerable<T> - это O(n), никто не захочет бежать по последнему куску.

Comment: @STDray: поскольку ТС не говорит о специфике _его_ задачи, нам приходится гадать.

---
Для вашего паттерна, возможно, `IEnumerable<>` излишен: его смысл как раз в обработке по 1 элементу, а не по `n`, и ленивому чтению их, вы же используете по существу блочное чтение.

Comment: @VladD, результат ToChunks - ленивая коллекция. Все вами сказанное про IEnumerable<T> справедливо для нее. Природа ее элементов не должна смущать. Что такое "блочное чтение" и как оно выражается в типах, я не знаю.

Comment: @STDray: мне не совсем понятен смысл фразы "выражается в типах", вы наверное адепт ФП? Есть стандартная идиома в C, когда в силу плохой буферизации в стандартной библиотеке приходится обрабатывать материализованными блоками.

    #define BUFSIZE 65536
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    while ((nread = fread(f, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
        if ((nwritten = fwrite(f, buf, BUFSIZE)) != nread)
            report_scary_error();

Смысл `IEnumerable<>`, как мне кажется, и состоит в том, что размер блока равен 1, а вопросы эффективности находятся строго в ведении нижележащих библиотек.

Comment: @VladD, IEnumerable<> - абстракция коллекций, имеет только одно свойство - получение enumerator'а, который позволяет получить текущий элемент и перейти к следующему. IEnumerable<> можно рассматривать как структуру данных и посчитать сложность операций над ней. Именно эти оценки надо брать за основу, потому что если сложность алгоритма базируется на O(1) для доступа к произвольному элементу, то не все коллекции подойдут.
Да, коллекции могут определять реализации методов с лучшими характеристиками, но абстракция этого не гарантирует. И если нужны более сильные требования лучше делать это явно.

Comment: @STDray 
>сформировать ленивый IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> за один проход сложно, ведь вызовы Skip(K * N).Take(N) приводят к неоднократному повторному итерированию по исходной коллекции

Если честно, не понял что мешает реализовать `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` без использования `Skip` и `Take`. Поясните пожалуйста.